# Golang build failed. Error package "XXX" is not in GOROOT "XXX"

Tags: go, dockerfile, continuous-integration

The Go App fails to build when I try to build in linux. The same app builds fine in Windows

The command that I use to build the project :  go build meddeals_server

It works properly on my windows machine, the issue arises when I dockerize it or deploy on cloud linux instance.

Folder Structure

```
C:\proj\MEDDEALS_SERVER
│   .gitignore
│   Dockerfile
│   go.mod
│   go.sum
│   main.go
│   meddeals_server.exe
│
├───.netlify
│       state.json
│
├───controller
│       Apollo.go
│       Buddy.go
│       Net.go
│       MG.go
│       Forever.go
│
├───entity
│       Apollo.go
│       GeoIP.go
│       MedCard.go
│       Buddy.go
│       Search.go
│       Net.go
│       One.go
│       Forever.go
│
└───utility
        HttpHelper.go
```

Error on Cloud

**Error: package meddeals_server/Controller is not in GOROOT (/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.19.3.linux.amd64/src/meddeals_server/Controller)**

Error on Docker

**#9 7.718 main.go:4:2: package meddeals_server/Controller is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/meddeals_server/Controller)
#9 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c go build -o main .]: exit code: 1**

It is strange that the same build command works fine on my windows machine but not in other environments.

Comment: Did you copy go.mod to the docker image?

Comment: Are you running the command from the correct directory? You are either running outside of the module, or have not copied the entire module over.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Yes i copied. If the mod file is not in directory then the error is different (no required module provides package main.go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go help modules')

Comment: @JimB, yes probably i am running it from the correct directory because the build process starts and fails in the middle. If it was in the wrong directory then the build process should have not started. A glimpse of build logs is as follows

Comment: `3:59:17 PM: $ go build main.go
3:59:17 PM: go: downloading github.com/gin-contrib/cors v1.4.0
3:59:17 PM: go: downloading github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.8.1
3:59:18 PM: go: downloading github.com/go-playground/universal-translator v0.18.0
3:59:18 PM: go: downloading golang.org/x/text v0.4.0
3:59:18 PM: go: downloading github.com/leodido/go-urn v1.2.1
3:59:18 PM: go: downloading github.com/go-playground/locales v0.14.0
3:59:19 PM: main.go:4:2: package meddeals_server/Controller is not in GOROOT (/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.19.3.linux.amd64/src/meddeals_server/Controller)`

Comment: `Controller` is uppper-case, the directory is lower-case.

Comment: Thanks @BurakSerdar, somehow the upper case issue was not there on my windows instance. but when I matched the go version on the cloud then the error became visible and I was able to resolve it.

Answer (score -1):

After a lot of retries, I have resolved the issue. The problem was the GO version was different on docker and other cloud instances which is why I was facing this issue. Because the error was misleading it took a lot of time to resolve it.

I matched the Go version on docker and cloud instance, then the build worked fine.

Thanks, Everybody!